# React-native, switch audio output from headphones to earpiece

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, mobile

Is There a way in react native force switching audio output from headphones to earpiece?
I already have a function to detect if the device is connected to an audio device (headphones, airpoods, loud speakers...)

Thanks in advance!

I need a way to change audio output from headphones to earpiece even if the device is connected to the headphones...

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Comment: In my current setup **yes**, I'm using LiveKit for video streaming, which offers the ability to change audio output. If you want to implement this feature, you'll need to use a third-party library or make changes in the native code.